# Swift - UICollectionView Not Scrolling With Screen

Tags: swift, xcode, autolayout

When using a `UICollectionView` I ran into this issue.[image: 1]]I need uicollectionview to scroll with the page instead of being cut off.Here is what im trying to get [image: 2]

Comment: Make sure the collection view's frame is what you want. You can add constraints to make it fill the size of its parent view (the window)

Comment: I need two collectionview's if I scroll down the collectionview movies not the screen it self.Which causes the other collectionview to stay on the top of the screen.

Comment: Why do you need two?

Comment: I trying to recreate the above image.